# How to use builder and stub in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, builder, stub

I try to build an application using a builder and a stub but i fail

My builder code :

```
File.Copy(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Camstub.exe", filepath);
            string split = "|";
            string info = split + CName.Text + split + Link.Text + split;

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
            fs.Position = fs.Length + 1;
            bw.Write(info);
            bw.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(info);
```

My stub code :

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(sr.BaseStream);
        byte[] fileData = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(sr.BaseStream.Length));
        br.Close();
        sr.Close();

        ASCIIEncoding Enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string split = "|";
        string Message = Enc.GetString(fileData);
        MessageBox.Show(Message);
```

The messagebox in the builder show me:

[image: http://embed.gyazo.com/d8f55ce5ea608b3861e64862242b0012.png]

The application is sucessfully build but the messagebox when i execute it show me:

[image]

So, I expect the same messagebox in both.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Your stub reads the first xxx bytes (xxx being equal to the file length) from the executable and puts them into *info* (note, that a Windows executable or DLL file always starts with the magic bytes "MZ"). In your builder, the variable *info* is composed from different data (*CName* and *Link*), so no surprise that you see differences between the stub and the builder messageboxes. There is no reason to expect the two messageboxes to show the same data...

Comment: Are you perhaps intending to read the Cname/Link data you appended at the end of the file? If so, is this Cname/Link data of constant length, i.e. a constant number of bytes; or can its length be variable?

Comment: Ty, hum so i have to read in the end of the file but the lenght of the CName/Link can be variable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information given in the comments, you want to read the *|CName|Link|* data from the end of the file. The *|CName|Link|* data can be of variable length.

To deal with variable length data you somehow need to indicate the byte length of the data. In the given scenario here, a simple and suitable solution would be to store the byte length as a 2-byte or 4-byte number at the end of the file after the *|CName|Link|* data. A 2-byte number (i.e., *ushort* or *UInt16*) allows to specify a length of up to 65536 and should likely be sufficient for your purpose. (If the data can be more than 64KB, then use 4 bytes to store the length.)

Thus, the builder should do the following:

1. Compose *|CName|Link|* string data and store it in the *info* variable.
2. Convert the string in *info* into a byte array with a chosen text encoding. (I would suggest using the UTF-8 text encoding.)
3. Append this byte array to the executable file.
4. Append the length of the byte array as a 2-byte number to the end of the executable file.

The stub should do something like this:

1. Determine the file size of the executable file.
2. Open the executable file for reading.
3. Set the current file position to fileSize-2, so the length of the *|CName|Link|* can be read.
4. Read the 2-byte number and store it into an *ushort* (or *int*) variable *dataLength*.
5. Set the current file position to fileSize-2-dataLength.
6. Read the bytes of the *|CName|Link|* data. The number of bytes to read is specified by *dataLength*.
7. Process the *|CName|Link|* data bytes. For example, convert them into a string, using the same(**!**) text encoding that has been used by the builder.

Comment: Thanks for you help, i'm pretty sure your solution is good but i have found an other one,  I add a string like "-START-" before "|CName|Link|" And i read all the stream and i keep information following "-START-"

Comment: Your stub program needs to read the whole file to find the "-start-" marker. A very inefficient way of doing things... With my approach only 2 + dataLength bytes are being read. But then again, i do not know your application scenario. Perhaps performance is irrelevant, and your approach is just fine for your purposes... :-)

Comment: But consider this: What if the executable file already contains "-START-" somewhere in its file data? Then your approach fails, whereas mine would still operate properly... Hint:  This will happen, because the "-START-" string literal would be a part of the compiled C# code and therefore already be part of the compiled executable file. :p